# reCAPTCHA v3 has started to return "Confirm that the SiteKey and SecretKey are setup properly for this service"

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, recaptcha

We've been utilizing Google reCAPTCHA v3 in our production for the past two years. Our website, a job board platform, allows users to apply for any matching jobs. Recently, we've received complaints from users stating they are unable to submit their requests. Upon checking the log files, we observed that reCAPTCHA is returning low scores and below error:
"Server Error, please confirm that the SiteKey and SecretKey are setup properly for this service. "

The only notable change on our site is that some posted jobs now include a very long list of questions. Users may spend 5 minutes or more on the page before hitting the Submit button. Also, in Admin Console, it shows over 1 million requests in pas week. Could this be the reason for the low scores?

I don't know how to resolve the issue?

Our application is an aps.net web application and we used https://github.com/WestleyBennett/reCAPTCHAv3 solution to implement reCAPTCHA in our site.

Any help or advise is appreciate

I generated a new sitekey, but unfortunately, that did not resolve the issue.